# How do I hide all the geometry in a scene that is contained in a box object?

Tags: 3dsmax

I have a nature scene that "stands" on z = 0 level, basically on the grey grid. I want to hide all the geometry bellow z = 0, which would be under a plane, or inside a very large box.

I don't want to use Boolean because it requires me to update group all my assets and insert them into operand B. But I have moving parts like water and stuff :|

now I KNOW its possible, I have done it like 2-3 years ago but I don't have access to the 3ds file anymore nor could I find the source website :(